# rails 4 with tag-it and jquery ui autocomplete edit form tags

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-autocomplete, tag-it, bootstrap-tokenfield

This issue has been bugging me for days and after frustrating switch from bootstrap-tokenfield to tag-it without much success in fixing the problem, I am posting here. I have a modal edit form that allows users to fix up their tags. When I display the tags in the edit form; however, I get this:

[image]

I have this setup here in controller :

```
@tag_list = []
@post.tags.each do |tag|
  ph_list = { value: tag.profile_id, label: "#{tag.name.capitalize}"}
  @tag_list << ph_list
end
@tag_list.to_json
respond_modal_with @post
```

when this setup from model didn't work:
    def tag_list
        tag_list = []

```
  tags.each do |tag|
    tag_list = { name: "#{tags.name}"}
    @profile = Profile.find(tag.profile_id)
    tag_list[:tag_url] = "#{@profile}"
  end
end
```

any hints or assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I never thought this whole token thing would be so hard. There's very little options and they don't particularly work that well or are supported. I'm trying to use the bootstrap version but it's only returning the first token and ignoring the rest

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: I wasn't having the exact same issue as you were. I was speaking on tokens in general. I  was having issues when  I was using the  cdn version of the script so I moved to the gem instead and things seem to be working for me.

Comment: I managed to get this setup working :P finally

Comment: @lifejuggler please post your solution as an answer.